# How to make a discord.js image search command when the bot is hosted on heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord, discord.js

I have a command in my Discord.js bot that is supposed to get a picture from dogpile and post it, but ever since I started hosting my bot on Heroku (I'm using it for free) it stopped working completely, I don't get any errors, here's the code:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");
const Discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    name: 'image',
    description: 'sends an image based on your search query',
    execute(message, args){
        
        image(message, args);

        function image(message, parts) {

            var search = parts.slice(0).join(" ");

            var options = {
                url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + search,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "text/html",
                    "User-Agent": "Chrome"
                }
            };


            request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
                if (error) {
                    return;
                }
                
                $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

                var links = $(".image a.link");

                var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

                console.log(urls);
                if(!urls.length) {
                    return;
                }

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Image of a(n) " + search)
                .setImage(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)])
                .setFooter('Searched by ' + message.author.username)
                .setColor("#43B581");
                message.channel.send(embed)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

this also might help but I'm not sure:
[Heroku Dyno Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZj7p.png)

Comment: There must be something that crash your bot try to wrap your code in `try{...}catch(e){...}` and then if no errors is caught . Please look into dyno logs if it's over usage or something that make dyno stop

Comment: im not getting any errors, but i did notice that it logs a blank array, normally it'll be full of links of images

Comment: Add more debugging logs and add the Heroku log anyway. You may see stuff that you deem irrelevant but is actually relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe becuase you transfered from repl.it to Heroku, because repl.it auto installs any missing modules while Heroku doesn't so make sure that you have `Cheerio` module installed.